# Javascript XMLHttpRequest not working on IE 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I did this script that works on IE10 and above. It also works on Opera, Chrome, Firefox.

```
function trackid() {
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open('GET', 'https://radio.riddimdub.com/playing.txt');
    client.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var trackName = client.responseText;
        document.getElementsByClassName("tracktitle")[0].innerHTML = trackName;
    };
    client.send()
};
trackid();
setInterval(trackid, 5000);
```

Now I changed it a little bit to make it work for IE9. I did this:

```
function trackid() {
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open('GET', 'https://radio.riddimdub.com/playing.txt');
    client.send()
    if (client.readyState === client.DONE) {
        var trackName = client.responseText;
        document.getElementsByClassName("tracktitle")[0].innerHTML = trackName;
    }
};
trackid();
setInterval(trackid, 5000);
```

The problem is that I get no error in Console on IE9, nor on Opera but it doesn't work on both.

Is worth to mention that I've also tried with:

```
try {
} finally {
}
```

Is there anything I did wrong?

Comment: Of course the request isn't going to be `DONE` immediately after you send it. You should also check to verify the readystate and the status before you try to use its `responseText`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Isn't client.readyState === client.DONE supposed to do that?

Comment: @SumutiuMarius The condition can only tell you if it completely already. It won't help you wait out the response. The `readystatechange` event, however, is one way to be informed as the response becomes available (and is compatible with IE9). Though, typically, you want to use the event and the check `client.readyState` together, as the event can/will trigger for other states. [MDN: Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange#Example)

Comment: Damn it. Thanks @JonathanLonowski for info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it. Thanks for the info guys. Here's how:

```
function trackid() {
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open('GET', 'https://radio.riddimdub.com/playing.txt');
    client.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (client.readyState === client.DONE) {
            var trackName = client.responseText;
            document.getElementsByClassName("tracktitle")[0].innerHTML = trackName;
        }
    }
    client.send()
};
trackid();
setInterval(trackid, 5000);
```